# How to train a network with two or more layers

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am implementing a neural network from scratch using python. I have a Neuron class, layer class and network class.

I have managed to train and use a network with 1 layer, 1 Neuron and 3 inputs.

I now want to try using 2 or more layers, both with an arbitrary number of Neurons. My problem is, how would I now change the 'train' function to train a network like this?

At present, if the layer is 0 then it will input the network inputs into the neurons. If the layer is above 0, then it will input the outputs from the previous layer.

But what do I do next?

I have used the code below:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp, random
import math

from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)

class Neuron:

    def __init__(self, weights, bias):

        self.weights = weights
        self.bias = bias

    def sigmoid(self, x):

        output = 1/(1+exp(-x))

        return output

    def compute(self, inputs):

        self.output = self.sigmoid(np.dot(inputs, self.weights) + self.bias)

        return self.output

class Layer: 

    def __init__(self, numberOfNeurons, numberOfInputs):

        self.neurons = []
        self.outputs = []
        self.numberOfNeurons = numberOfNeurons
        self.numberOfInputs = numberOfInputs

        self.initialiseWeightsAndBiases()

        for i in range(0,numberOfNeurons):

            self.neurons.append(Neuron(self.weights, self.biases))

    def initialiseWeightsAndBiases(self):

        self.weights = 2 * random.random((self.numberOfInputs, self.numberOfNeurons)) - 1

        self.biases = 2 * random.random((1, self.numberOfNeurons)) - 1

    
    def forward(self, inputs):

        self.outputs = np.array([])

        for i in self.neurons:

            self.outputs = np.append(self.outputs, i.compute(inputs))

class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, layers):

        self.layers = layers

    def forwardPass(self, inputs):

        for i in range(0,len(layers)):

            if i == 0:

                layers[i].forward(inputs)   

            else:
                
                layers[i].forward(layers[i-1].outputs)

        return layers[-1].outputs

    def calculateError(self, predictedOutputs, trueOutputs):

        error = (trueOutputs - predictedOutputs) * predictedOutputs * (1 - predictedOutputs)

        return error

    def trainNetwork(self, trainingDataInputs, trainingDataOutputs, numberOfIterations):

        #initialise the best weights with random values

        for y in range(0, numberOfIterations):

            predictedOutputs = self.forwardPass(trainingDataInputs)

            error = self.calculateError(predictedOutputs, trainingDataOutputs)

            for i in layers[0].neurons:             

                i.weights += np.dot(trainingDataInputs.T, error.T)


    def visualiseNetwork(self):

        pass


#Layer(numberOfNeurons, numberOfInputs)

inputLayer = Layer( 1, 3)

layers = [inputLayer]

network1 = NeuralNetwork(layers)

inputTrainingData = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]])
outputTrainingData = [[0, 1, 1, 0]]

network1.trainNetwork(inputTrainingData, outputTrainingData, 10000)

outputs = network1.forwardPass([[0,1,1]])

print(outputs)
```

Comment: I found this online [book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) by Michael Nielson extremely helpful to understanding how to build a neural net trainer from scratch, for those that are interested.

Comment: You need to use back-propagation. Have a look at the answer that mentions back propagation

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. I have done exactly this as an assignment. You need a list in Layer to store error for every layer.
Starting with the last layer, the error will get backpropagated till the first layer.

```
def trainNetwork(self, trainingDataInputs, trainingDataOutputs, numberOfIterations):
    #initialise the best weights with random values
    for y in range(0, numberOfIterations):
        predictedOutputs = self.forwardPass(trainingDataInputs)
        error = self.calculateError(predictedOutputs, trainingDataOutputs)
        for i in layers[0].neurons:             
            i.weights += np.dot(trainingDataInputs.T, error.T)

        N = predictedOutputs.len()
        next_layer = layers[-1]
        next_layer.error = error

        for i in range(len(layers) - 2, -1):
            next_layer = layers[i+1]
            current_layer = layers[i]
            current_layer.error = np.dot(next_layer.error, next_layer.weights.T) * current_layer.output * (1-current_layer.output)
            for i in next_layer.neurons:
                i.weights += np.dot(current_layer.output.T, next_layer.error)/N

        # for the first layer, updating weights needs to be done against the inputs
        for i in current_layer.neurons:
            i.weights += np.dot(trainingDataInputs.T, current_layer.error)/N
```

*PS: Correct me if I am wrong but weight updation formula is np.dot(trainingDataInputs.T, error.T) for your code
You can also add learning rate to your code
*

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, A neural network with an input layer, two hidden layers, and an output layer. The network is trained on the XOR problem dataset, and you can test it by passing different inputs to the **forward_pass** method

```
import numpy as np

class Neuron:
    def __init__(self, weights, bias):
        self.weights = weights
        self.bias = bias

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

    def compute(self, inputs):
        weighted_sum = np.dot(inputs, self.weights) + self.bias
        return self.sigmoid(weighted_sum)

class Layer:
    def __init__(self, num_neurons, num_inputs):
        self.neurons = []
        self.outputs = []
        self.num_neurons = num_neurons
        self.num_inputs = num_inputs
        self.initialize_weights_and_biases()

        for _ in range(num_neurons):
            self.neurons.append(Neuron(self.weights, self.biases))

    def initialize_weights_and_biases(self):
        self.weights = 2 * np.random.random((self.num_inputs, self.num_neurons)) - 1
        self.biases = 2 * np.random.random((1, self.num_neurons)) - 1

    def forward(self, inputs):
        self.outputs = np.array([])
        for neuron in self.neurons:
            self.outputs = np.append(self.outputs, neuron.compute(inputs))

class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, layers):
        self.layers = layers

    def forward_pass(self, inputs):
        for layer in self.layers:
            layer.forward(inputs)
            inputs = layer.outputs
        return inputs

    def calculate_error(self, predicted_outputs, true_outputs):
        error = (true_outputs - predicted_outputs) * predicted_outputs * (1 - predicted_outputs)
        return error

    def train_network(self, training_data_inputs, training_data_outputs, num_iterations):
        for _ in range(num_iterations):
            for i, layer in enumerate(self.layers):
                if i == 0:
                    layer.forward(training_data_inputs)
                else:
                    layer.forward(self.layers[i - 1].outputs)

            predicted_outputs = self.layers[-1].outputs
            error = self.calculate_error(predicted_outputs, training_data_outputs)

            for i, layer in enumerate(reversed(self.layers)):
                prev_outputs = (
                    self.layers[-i - 2].outputs if i < len(self.layers) - 1 else training_data_inputs
                )
                layer_back = layer.neurons if i == 0 else layer_back

                for j, neuron in enumerate(layer.neurons):
                    neuron.weights += np.dot(prev_outputs.T, error[:, j])
                    neuron.bias += np.sum(error[:, j])

                error = np.dot(error, layer.weights.T)

def main():
    # XOR problem dataset
    input_training_data = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
    output_training_data = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0]]).T

    input_layer = Layer(2, 2)
    hidden_layer1 = Layer(3, 2)
    hidden_layer2 = Layer(3, 3)
    output_layer = Layer(1, 3)

    layers = [input_layer, hidden_layer1, hidden_layer2, output_layer]

    network = NeuralNetwork(layers)

    network.train_network(input_training_data, output_training_data, num_iterations=10000)

    test_input = np.array([[0, 1, 1]])
    predicted_output = network.forward_pass(test_input)
    print("Predicted output for [0, 1, 1]:", predicted_output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```